# Not loading element oustide the window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble to make WPF load an element outside the window.

Here is my problem : everything that will be not inside of the window when it loads will not be displayed, even if I make them back in the window using storyboard.

Here is an exemple of what is happening inside of the XAML editor of Visual Studio :
I create a big button, i make a `Storyboard` using `TranslateTransform` to make it back inside the viewable area :

As you can see there, the button is cut according to the window boundary :

[image: Before the storyboard moves it]

And then I move it using a Storyboard, and the rest of the button isn't shown.

[image: After the storyboard moves it]

Any idea why is this happening ? I tried with a blank project and I havn't be able to reproduce that bug.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about, let alone what you are asking. Please clearly describe exactly what you need help with and please provide some code to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Edited my post, describing problems more clearly using screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you... I think I see your problem now. Can you please provide the code that you are using so that we can test it?

Comment: There is only XAML. With two grids : One have `ClipToBound=True`, and I make the other one slides horizontaly inside using storyboard. The only property my Window have is `ResizeMode="NoResize`

Comment: If you show us your XAML, maybe we can find a problem in it and solve your issue. If you don't, we cant... it's up to you.

Comment: Here is the XAML I use : http://seban.eu/test.txt

Comment: I loaded up your XAML in a new project, but after removing the event handlers and `Resources`, I don't see your problem anywhere. Can you provide a smaller example of just your problem... I often used to find the solution to my problems when I tried to simplify them in order to show an example here.

Comment: This is really strange... Even with visual states ? I mean, you can switch between them ?

Comment: I had to remove all references to the event handlers because I have no idea what code is in there.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here is what I use to switch between states : http://seban.eu/test2.txt
But i don't think it's related

Comment: Input and Output don't appear to do anything and the Space and shape button seems to work fine... I'm not seeing anything getting cut off. However, it occurs to me that you have a lot of animation code... would it not be simpler to animate the `Grid` controls that contain the other controls?